# Unzip items from list of tuples in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have 3 lists that I am combining in a specific way (using izip). then i am performing a calculation on the combined list of tuples. once the calculation is done however, i need to 'undo' this operation to get the original list back (albeit with some values changed). Is there a simple pythonic way of doing this?

```
grouped = []

med_done = 0
lrg_done = 0        

#While items exist in small, pair up one item from each list
grouped.extend(list(izip(sml,med,lrg)))

done = len(sml)

# While items remain in med, pair up one from med an two from lrg
grouped.extend(list(izip(med[done:],lrg[done::2],lrg[(done+1)::2])))

done = done + (2*(len(med)-len(sml)))

# Finish pairing up remaining items from lrg
grouped.extend(list(izip_longest(lrg[done::3],lrg[(done+1)::3],lrg[(done+2)::3],fillvalue = '-')))
```

This produces:

```
smlBinary:[6 6 7 7 7 8 6 8 7]

medBinary:[4 3 4 3 3 3 5 5 4 5 3 5 3 3 4 4]

lrgBinary:[0 1 2 0 0 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 2 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 1]

Grouped[(6, 4, 0), (6, 3, 1), (7, 4, 2), (7, 3, 0), (7, 3, 0), (8, 3, 2), (6, 5, 1), (8, 5, 1), (7, 4, 1), (5, 0, 1), (3, 2, 0), (5, 0, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1), (0, 2, 1), (2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, '-', '-')]
```

QUESTION:
Now is there a similar technique I could use to 'unpair' these items back to get the original lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of variable arguments and the zip function to unzip.

```
unzipped = zip(*zipped)
```

Where `zipped` is your `grouped` variable.

Comment: Hi @EyuelDK, yes, i was hoping to use something like that but I would need to do it in 3 'pieces' the same as the izip part but without using loops.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but 'unzipped', in your case, should become an array of length 3 where each array is the original, i.e. sml, med, lrg.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding right, you just need to split out the tuples into lists? Don't know much about izip, but it looks like you could just do it with a few list comprehensions:

```
sm_out = [tup[0] for tup in grouped]
med_out = [tup[1] for tup in grouped]
lg_out = [tup[2] for tup in grouped]
```

Comment: Hi @Anddrrw , If it was paired up evenly your method would work perfectly but the way the pairing works means I cant use a single method for the entire 'grouped' list. at the very least it has to be done in 3 pieces.